# lambda function to random color

Tags: python, random

I want generate RGB color with Lambda function. I have tried to do this code:

```
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
color=[r,r,r]

print(r)
color
```

Output:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7f2aca8a7c20>
  
  [<function __main__.<lambda>>,
   <function __main__.<lambda>>,
   <function __main__.<lambda>>]
```

I did not even get one number (r). Can anyone explain to me why this function is not good?

---

***Update and Edit:***

I realized that the lambda is a function that receives no value r()
But how do you make the paint work in the same method and not permanently

If it is possible to convert a variable to a random number - that will not be in the function.
That is, whenever a variable is available it will be different?

Comment: `color=[r(),r(),r()]`

Comment: You didn't _call_ the function...

Comment: Related: [Purpose of calling function without brackets python](/q/21785933/4518341), [What is the difference between calling function with parentheses and without in python?](/q/46001292/4518341)

Comment: I don't understand the edit. 1) `r()` is not void, it returns an `int`. 2) What do you mean by "paint"? 3) What do you mean by the last paragraph? Is that what you're trying to accomplish? Why? Beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: My target is write "randcolor" and get every time another color

Comment: Related? [Call a function in repl without brackets](/q/68280186/4518341) or [Possible to call single-parameter Python function without using parentheses?](/q/2932887/4518341). Both cover IPython's `%autocall`, which might be what you want since it looks like you're using IPython. You would just need to write the function `randcolor`.

Answer (score 3):

The function is fine, but you never called it.

```
color = [r(), r(), r()]
```

If this syntax is not familiar to you, [it's mentioned in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

By the way, [avoid named lambdas](/q/38381556/4518341), use a `def` instead.

```
def r():
    return random.randint(0, 255)
```